# "Ella es nuestra madre" - Why is "nuestra" feminine?

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras, gramática

Why is `nuestra` feminine if we do not know the gender of the people the speaker is referring?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ok, I must confess, at first I thought the question wouldn't make sense, but it does and actually it's quite interesting.

In Spanish adjectives, possessives pronouns, and so on are declined according to the noun they qualify. In this case, *nuestra* is qualifying *madre*, which is *always* feminine (unless..., no, always feminine).

Let's compare with other languages, (e.g. English). In English your possessive pronouns *only* refer, if at all, to the gender of the object which possesses. Thus in

> She is Mary. **Her** mother is beautiful.

or, for sake of generalization to plural, in

> She is Mary. **Her** grandmothers were beautiful.

the only reference to gender and number is on the object that possesses the *mother* or the *grandmothers*, *Mary* in this case. This means, the possessive pronoun detects if the subject here is a *Mary* or *John Smith* (which implies *her* should be replaced *his*) but it doesn't deliver information whatsoever about the object that the subject possesses (if it's a mother, or a father or two grandmothers or 1024 great-great-...-great-grandpa's, that doesn't affect the possessive pronoun.)

However, Spanish is –as many other languages are– endowed with an additional gender and number slot: the noun that is "possessed"

> Nuestra madre

means *our mother* but the gender information there refers to *mother*, not to us.

Comment: +1, and LOL for "(unless..., no, always feminine)"